# How to manage environments on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

In our company, we are adding administrator role to all devs. I think this is a big risk, and now I want to restrict devs privileges. My goal is that a dev can add any resource, but can't touch test and production environments.

I was thinking to make a group on IAM and set the following policy, but maybe there is a better approach.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*:*",
            "Resource": "*-dev-*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a set of best practices to work with several environments (dev, test, prod) on AWS?

Comment: As this isn't a programming question, it's off-topic for StackOverflow, and it's probably too broad & opinion-based for Server Fault. There are myriad ways to handle this. Try some web searches, there's a ton of information available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to have completely separate AWS accounts, one or more just for production and one or more for just for dev/test environments.

For billing purposes you can tie them altogether if you want to.

You definitely don't want all of your devs to have administrator access to your prod environment, and a separate account will help limit the possibility of a catastrophic mistake being made.